# How can I install pyCurl?

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl, installation

I used libcurl with no problems and used pyCurl once in the past. Now i want to set it up on my machine and dev. However i have no idea how to do it. I rather not DL libcirl files and compile that along with pycurl, i want to know the simplest method. I have libcurl installed on my machine.

I am on Windows. I tried DLing the sources and use pycurl setup script, but I had no luck.

Comment: @Chitimalli not only is 'feb 3 09' 6yr ago, your link is to this very post

Answer (score 19):

**TL,DR**

Get a binary from this website: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Direct links: [`2.6 32bit`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/qjbh48zu/pycurl-7.19.0.win32-py2.6.exe), 
[`2.7 32bit`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/qjbh48zu/pycurl-7.19.0.win32-py2.7.exe),[`2.6 64bit`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/qjbh48zu/pycurl-7.19.0.win-amd64-py2.6.exe), [`2.7 64bit`](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/qjbh48zu/pycurl-7.19.0.win-amd64-py2.7.exe)

---

For pycURL, both `pip` and `easy_install` will fail on Windows.

I also tried to download and install the pycURL package manually, after
downloading cURL, but that didn't work either, even if specifying the
`CURL_DIR` ( it complained that it cannot find 'lib\libcurl.lib' ).  From what
I can gather from the README, what it needs in the `CURL_DIR` is the source
distribution of cURL, not the executable.

Downloading the precompiled version from the official [pycURL
repository](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/) will probably get you
nowhere, because it requires Python 2.5. It will *not* work with 2.6.

The only easy way at the moment seems to be
[this](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/5kq9gygp/pycurl-7.19.0.win32-py2.6.exe)
unofficial release. It an executable installer, and I have used it without any
issues with Python 2.6. A [version for Python
2.7](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/5kq9gygp/pycurl-7.19.0.win32-py2.7.exe)
is available from [the same site](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

---

You might also want to consider using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), a popular alternative to pycURL. It's a pleasure to use, and is actively developed.

Comment: I long ago considered moving off Windows, but now that desire is stronger than ever

Comment: This is poor package maintenance on the pycURL side, nothing to do with Windows.

Comment: I love requests usability as well, however, could be that the motive behind picking pycurl has to do with performance https://stackoverflow.com/a/32899936/2128265

Comment: The binaries don't exist anymore :(

Answer (score 15):

You can try to download pycurl from here

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

> PycURL is a interface to the libcurl library.
>   pycurl-7.19.0.win-amd64-py2.6.‌exe  [863 KB]  [Python 2.6]  [64 bit]  [Dec 09, 2010]
>   pycurl-7.19.0.win-amd64-py2.7.‌exe  [863 KB]  [Python 2.7]  [64 bit]  [Dec 09, 2010]
>   pycurl-7.19.0.win32-py2.6.‌exe  [764 KB]  [Python 2.6]  [32 bit]  [Dec 09, 2010]
>   pycurl-7.19.0.win32-py2.7.‌exe  [764 KB]  [Python 2.7]  [32 bit]  [Dec 09, 2010]

or here

http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/

> pycurl-ssl-7.15.5.1.win32-py2.4.exe    02-Oct-2006 10:10   534K    precompiled win32 installer (with openssl-0.9.8c, zlib-1.2.3, c-ares-1.3.1)
>   pycurl-ssl-7.15.5.1.win32-py2.5.exe 02-Oct-2006 10:10   534K    precompiled win32 installer (with openssl-0.9.8c, zlib-1.2.3, c-ares-1.3.1)
>   pycurl-ssl-7.16.4.win32-py2.4.exe   05-Sep-2007 19:28   546K    precompiled win32 installer (with openssl-0.9.8e, zlib-1.2.3, c-ares-1.4.0)
>   pycurl-ssl-7.16.4.win32-py2.5.exe   05-Sep-2007 19:27   546K    precompiled win32 installer (with openssl-0.9.8e, zlib-1.2.3, c-ares-1.4.0)
>   pycurl-ssl-7.18.2.win32-py2.5.exe   17-Jun-2008 20:43   540K    precompiled win32 installer (with openssl-0.9.8h, zlib-1.2.3)

Comment: Avira is giving me an error why I try going to the first link, just thought I'd put that here.

Answer (score 13):

Depends on platform. Here on ubuntu it's as simple as:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pycurl
```

It's common enough a package to think that most major Linux distributions will have it in their sources.

If you're on windows, you'll need [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) too. Then you can install [pycurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/) which comes wrapped in an installer.

Comment: If you've already done this, but pip blows up when it also tries to install it (e.g. for pyresttest), try installing libcurl4-openssl-dev as well.

Answer (score 12):

According to http://bazaar-vcs.org/PyCurl

> Since Windows does not come with
>   neither cURL or pycURL, Windows users
>   will have to install both.
>
> cURL downloads:
>   http://curl.haxx.se/download.html.
>
> pycURL downloads:
>   http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/.
>
> Both links contain Linux (and other
>   *Nix) tarballs/packages and Windows installer files.

There are windows installers at both links, hopefully they will work for you.

Answer (score 7):

As it has been said already, it depends on the platform.

In general, I prefer to use only the Python interpreter itself that is packaged for my OS and install everything else in a [virtual environment](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv), but this is a whole different story...
If you've got [setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools/) installed, installing most Python packages is as simple as:

```
easy_install pycurl
```

Comment: This is not very descriptive...
In case you had trouble installing setuptools, check out my answer again, I edited the link to point to pypi (Python Package Index), that page also has instructions for installing setuptools on Windows.
Good luck!

Comment: That is what I get after installing curl in Windows, when I try to easy_install pycurl : AssertionError: please check CURL_DIR in setup.py

Comment: I finally download it and manually installed it instead of using easy_install.

Comment: Worked for me on a Windows 7 box. I installed cURL first, and then easy_install handled the pycURL install with no issues.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev
pip install pycurl
```

Answer (score 1):

My environment is Windows 7 and Python 2.7. Although my Windows 7 is 64-bit, my Python 2.7 is 32-bit.

I had success by visiting http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/ and downloading and running pycurl-7.19.3.win32-py2.7.msi.

Comment: it says forbidden

Answer (score 0):

Windows: 
python 3.7.1
Download `.msi` from https://dl.bintray.com/pycurl/pycurl/ and install, it works perfectly.