# How can i execute the following code using pycurl

Tags: python, pycurl

```
curl https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheets -H "Authorization: Bearer 26lhbngfsybdayabz6afrc6dcd" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d @test.json
```

Comment: i am very new to coding, so i dont even know how to start :\

Comment: Start here: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pycurl+tutorial

Comment: any syntax suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are new to coding, then don't use `pycurl` it is generally considered obsolete. Instead use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) which can be installed with `pip install requests`.

Here is how to do the equivalent with `requests`:

```
import requests

with open('test.json') as data:
    headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer 26lhbngfsybdayabz6afrc6dcd'
               'Content-Type' : 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post('https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheets', headers=headers, data=data)
print r.json
```

If you must use `pycurl` I suggest that you start [reading here](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/quickstart.html#retrieving-a-network-resource). Generally it would be done by this (untested) code:

```
import pycurl

with open('test.json') as json:
    data = json.read()

    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://api.smartsheet.com/1.1/sheets')
    c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)
    c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Authorization: Bearer 26lhbngfsybdayabz6afrc6dcd',
                                 'Content-Type: application/json'])
    c.perform()
```

This shows that `requests` is far more elegant.

Comment: actually it's not really obsolete. pycurl is also much faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32899936/1515686

Comment: @Tom-OliverHeidel: That's interesting. By _generally obselete_ I mean that there are some specialist cases where it might be used, but in the general case, for a beginner, `requests` is so much better (and faster) to work with that I would not recommend `pycurl` unless there is a demonstrable need to use it.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right. I actually prefer requests over pycurl. Also pycurl could need some better documentation to be honest.