# Confusing about StringIO, cStringIO and ByteIO

Tags: python, stringio, bytesio, cstringio

I have googled and also search on SO for the difference between these buffer modules. However, I still don't understand very well and I think some of the posts I read are out of date.

In Python 2.7.11, I downloaded a binary file of a specific format using `r = requests.get(url)`. Then I passed `StringIO.StringIO(r.content)`, `cStringIO.StringIO(r.content)` and `io.BytesIO(r.content)` to a function designed for parsing the content.

All these three methods are available. I mean, even if the file is binary, it's still feasible to use `StringIO`. Why?

Another thing is concerning their efficiency.

```
In [1]: import StringIO, cStringIO, io

In [2]: from numpy import random

In [3]: x = random.random(1000000)

In [4]: %timeit y = cStringIO.StringIO(x)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 736 ns per loop

In [5]: %timeit y = StringIO.StringIO(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 283 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit y = io.BytesIO(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.26 ms per loop
```

As illustrated above, `cStringIO > StringIO > BytesIO`.

I found someone mentioned that `io.BytesIO` always makes a new copy which costs more time. But there are also some posts mentioned that this was fixed in later Python versions.

So, can anyone make a thorough comparison between these `IO`s, in both latest Python 2.x and 3.x?

---

Some of the reference I found:

- https://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/12046

  > io.StringIO requires a unicode string. io.BytesIO requires a bytes string. StringIO.StringIO allows either unicode or bytes string. cStringIO.StringIO requires a string that is encoded as a bytes string.

But `cStringIO.StringIO('abc')` doesn't raise any error.

- https://review.openstack.org/#/c/286926/1

  > The StringIO class is the wrong class to use for this, especially considering that subunit v2 is binary and not a string.
- http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/148717

  > cStringIO.StringIO(b'data') didn't copy the data while io.BytesIO(b'data') makes a copy (even if the data is not modified later).

There is a fix patch in this post in 2014.

- Lots of SO posts not listed here.

---

Here are the Python 2.7 results for Eric's example

```
%timeit cStringIO.StringIO(u_data)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 488 ns per loop
%timeit cStringIO.StringIO(b_data)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 448 ns per loop
%timeit StringIO.StringIO(u_data)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 µs per loop
%timeit StringIO.StringIO(b_data)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 µs per loop
%timeit io.StringIO(u_data)
1000 loops, best of 3: 304 µs per loop
# %timeit io.StringIO(b_data)
# error
# %timeit io.BytesIO(u_data)
# error
%timeit io.BytesIO(b_data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.5 µs per loop
```

As for 2.7, `cStringIO.StringIO` and `StringIO.StringIO` are far more efficient than `io`.

Comment: Can you label each of your snippets as python 2 or python 3?

Comment: @Eric, I did all my tests in Python 2.7.11. It seems `(c)StringIO` is replaced by `io` in 3. I mainly use 2.7. But I think it would be meaningful for other readers to discuss both versions.

Comment: [`io`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html) is in python 2 as well

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should use `io.StringIO` for handling `unicode` objects and `io.BytesIO` for handling `bytes` objects in both python 2 and 3, for forwards-compatibility (this is all 3 has to offer).

---

Here's a better test (for python 2 and 3), that doesn't include conversion costs from numpy to `str`/`bytes`

```
import numpy as np
import string
b_data = np.random.choice(list(string.printable), size=1000000).tobytes()
u_data = b_data.decode('ascii')
u_data = u'\u2603' + u_data[1:]  # add a non-ascii character
```

And then:

```
import io
%timeit io.StringIO(u_data)
%timeit io.StringIO(b_data)
%timeit io.BytesIO(u_data)
%timeit io.BytesIO(b_data)
```

In python 2, you can also test:

```
import StringIO, cStringIO
%timeit cStringIO.StringIO(u_data)
%timeit cStringIO.StringIO(b_data)
%timeit StringIO.StringIO(u_data)
%timeit StringIO.StringIO(b_data)
```

Some of these will crash, complaining about non-ascii characters

---

Python 3.5 results:

```
>>> %timeit io.StringIO(u_data)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.61 ms per loop
>>> %timeit io.StringIO(b_data)
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes
>>> %timeit io.BytesIO(u_data)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
>>> %timeit io.BytesIO(b_data)
The slowest run took 6.79 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached
1000000 loops, best of 3: 344 ns per loop
```

Python 2.7 results (run on a different machine):

```
>>> %timeit io.StringIO(u_data)
1000 loops, best of 3: 304 µs per loop
>>> %timeit io.StringIO(b_data)
TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str
>>> %timeit io.BytesIO(u_data)
TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface
>>> %timeit io.BytesIO(b_data)
10000 loops, best of 3: 77.5 µs per loop
```

```
>>> %timeit cStringIO.StringIO(u_data)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec cant encode character u'\u2603' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> %timeit cStringIO.StringIO(b_data)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 448 ns per loop
>>> %timeit StringIO.StringIO(u_data)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.15 µs per loop
>>> %timeit StringIO.StringIO(b_data)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.19 µs per loop
```

Comment: So in 3.x, `BytesIO` is distinct from and much faster than `StringIO`, in contrast to in 2.x.

Comment: `io.BytesIO` and `io.StringIO` are not comparable, as one only works on binary input, and the other only works on unicode strings

Comment: I complemented the 2.7 tests. Maybe you can put them in your post?

Comment: `cStringIO.StringIO(u_data)` errors on my machine, Did you run the line that inserts a unicode snowman?

Comment: `u_data[0]` is `\t`

Comment: @Lee: No way. `u_data[0]` is clearly `u'\u2603'`, because that's what I set it to. Did you forget to run my last line?

Comment: I ran your old codes. I remember `u'\u2603'` wasn't in your last post. Now an exception is raised. `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2603' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @Lee: Right, that's what I'd expect. `cStringIO` is unsafe to use on `unicode` data, as it can fail at runtime depending on the value.

Comment: So `BytesIO` is both safer and faster to use in python 3x compared to `StringIO` !

Comment: No @stormfield, it is not safer. One is for `str`, the other is for `bytes`. Choose based on what type of data you're writing, not on speed.

Comment: These time tests are not very helpful, because you only measure the time for creating the `StringIO` object but not the time for using it, which is what really matters. A better test would be to perform multiple `read`s or call a function such as `readlines()`.

Comment: What I don't understand is if I want to process the file byte-by-byte with Python 2.7 regardless of the encoding or anything, so I use `io.BytesIO`, then why the hell on the Earth does it complain about Unicode? Why does it matter if the binary data is Unicode or not? This is retarded. I just want to access the bytes...

Comment: @CsabaToth: I have no idea what you're trying to say but I think 1) it stems from a confusion between unicode code points and bytes, and 2) would be far easier to understand if you asked it as a new question

Comment: @CsabaToth If you simply want to store a bunch of text data and read it all at once, and you're okay with encoding your string as a binary object with the `.encode()` method, then `BytesIO` works just fine (remember to `.decode` the resulting binary back to a string). But if you plan to work on it like a Unicode text file, and want `.seek(1)` to seek by actually one character, then you have to use `StringIO`.