# python-requests iter_content implementation using pycurl

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, pycurl, http-streaming

I want to replace requests with pycurl in my existing code base. Is it possible to write interface similar to that of requests?

In particular I am looking for a drop in replacement for requests `.iter_content()` method.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to replace `requests` with `pycurl`, especially if you want the same interface?

Comment: @mhawke we are facing issues with NTLM authentication when using requests module; it works fine with pycurl.

Comment: Are you aware of [requests-ntlm](https://github.com/requests/requests-ntlm). Also see the same package at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests_ntlm.

Comment: @mhawke yes. I am using this as of now in my project.

Comment: Are the problems with `requests` insurmountable? What are they?

Comment: @mhawke 1) we are getting 401 in response from certain exchange servers. at the same time other modules that use pycurl are working fine with same exchange servers. 2) i would want to take advantage of pycurl's performance http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461995/python-requests-vs-pycurl-performance. this is something that was not evaluated before.