# Can't install pycurl with pip

Tags: python, installation, pip, pycurl

Can't install pycurl with pip, win xp x32, python 2.7.

here is the log

```
pip install pycurl
Downloading/unpacking pycurl
  Downloading pycurl-7.19.3.1.tar.gz (116Kb): 116Kb downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package pycurl
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 10 in C:\Documents and S
ettings\User\build\pycurl
Storing complete log in C:\Documents and Settings\User\Application Data\pip\pi
p.log
```

Comment: Did you specify the --curl-dir ? Like the log said "Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl"

Comment: Since you are on Windows, you have to install cURL before pycurl: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507927/how-do-i-install-pycurl

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: This question has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58847770/10146012)

Answer (score 28):

Following the steps one mentioned above, solved my problem.

```
sudo apt install libcurl4-gnutls-dev librtmp-dev

pip install pycurl
```

Answer (score 9):

This is a problem indeed. No need to update pip or easy install as it's often advised, well it won't hurt to update but you will still have the problem until you :

1. install libcurl4-gnutls-dev librtmp-dev packages
2. pip install pycurl

Worked the same in Linux

Comment: On CentOS, I get the error, "No package libcurl4-gnutls-dev available" and "No package librtmp-dev available."

Answer (score 5):

Here are easy steps I did to get around this:

1. Download the wheel of the version you want here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
2. then you can pip install that like so:

   pip install C:\sample\sample_dir\whl_file_downloaded

You should know be able to import in your python files

Comment: Real solution! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I was able to install it with easy_install instead:

```
easy_install pycurl
```

For easy_install, see [setuptools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools).

Comment: with easy_install, I still get the C:\Lib\site-packages error

Answer (score 4):

install pycurl using conda, conda will install all dependencies, Hope it works

`conda install -c anaconda pycurl`

Answer (score 1):

steps to follow :

1. `brew install openssl`
2. `PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" pip install --no-cache-dir pycurl`

Comment: I did a slight variation: PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/include" pip3 install --no-cache-dir pycurl

Answer (score 0):

For Linux Please install the `libcurl-devel` package and then try. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, and previous solutions did not work form me. And I had to change the path for openssl
I am commenting it here, I believe it might save someone's time.
Machine I am using

```
MacOS: Apple M1 Pro (Ventura v13.4)

pip uninstall pycurl
PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include" pip install --no-cache-dir pycurl
```

Answer (score -3):

So has said by Hai Vu you need to install cURL first.
Here is the dowload page : http://curl.haxx.se/download.html
I suggest you install it in your C:/ directory, or if you already installed it elsewhere copye the curl.exe file to your c:/

When done, you can try it by going to the cmd prompt :

```
cd c:/
curl "your-curl-request"
```

If it works then curl is correctly installed and you can install pycurl with pip.

Comment: Downvoting because this 1) doesn't work 2) putting executables in the system drive root is terrible advice.