# pycurl pip install for python 3.4

Tags: python, pycurl

I am installing  pycurl  for python 3.4,

if I run "pip install pycurl",  I have:

```
Downloading/unpacking pycurl
  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\kkw\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_kkw\p
ycurl\setup.py) egg_info for package pycurl
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Please specify --curl-dir=/path/to/built/libcurl

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 10 in C:\Users\kai.wen\A
ppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_kai.wen\pycurl
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\kai.wen\pip\pip.log
```

if I run  "pip install pycurl --curl-dir=C:\Python34\pycurl", I will have:

```
Usage:
  pip install [options] <requirement specifier> ...
  pip install [options] -r <requirements file> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <vcs project url> ...
  pip install [options] [-e] <local project path> ...
  pip install [options] <archive url/path> ...

no such option: --curl-dir
```

anyone has a working example to "pip install" pycurl?

Thanks

Comment: You may find what you're looking for here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/507927/how-do-i-install-pycurl

Answer (score 0):

Do you HAVE to use pip?

I got pycurl installed using `sudo easy_install pycurl`