# Python: urlopen() versus CURL

Tags: python, curl, pycurl

I'm writing a webcrawler using Python and enjoying it a lot! But I've noticed some differences between the result produced by `urlopen(url).read()` on Python and by `curl` on terminal. I tried to [install the pycurl module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507927/how-do-i-install-pycurl) with no success. Is there a simple way to produce the CURL result on Python?

**UPDATE**

In this case I parsed [this](http://buscando.extra.com.br/search?w=arroz) URL. I passed the same headers on both requests `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0`. Here are the outputs:

- cURL output: http://pastebin.com/PmmNhsbba
- urlopen output: http://pastebin.com/7Wrt8pQZ

Comment: what differences - please post both outputs for a small page

Comment: **cURL:** http://pastebin.com/PmmNhsbb
**Python:** http://pastebin.com/7Wrt8pQZ

Comment: I need to capture the elements with class `hproduct`. It is on the cURL version, but doesn't on the Python urlopen version.

Comment: It seems like the server is sending different content for the two requests.  I suggest you see what headers cURL is using and try duplicating those with urlopen.

Comment: I'm passing the same header on both requests `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question but maybe the answer can be still useful.

I had the same problem and what I did to solve it  was creating a php file which printed the request headers. Then I executed a `curl` and an `urlopen` and I checked the differences between the headers. You can find an example of that script in [PHP docs](https://secure.php.net/manual/es/function.getallheaders.php#example-5309).

In addition, you can go to your browser and check which headers are being send.  Doing this I saw that `urlopen` sends `connection: close` instead of `keep-alive`.

So finally I add the `keep-alive` header and `urlopen` began to work as `curl`. This was my concrete problem but maybe yours is different due to the server requirements and you need to add or remove another header.

Comment: Thanks for your coop! :)